# Auto Close Modal that will activate the function timer multiple times

Tags: javascript, html

So my problem is here: I tried to set a timer function that closes the modal but I noticed the modal is only closed once. I pressed the button again to show the modal but it stays there and it doesn't hide anymore.

heres my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      setTimeout(function(){
    $('#dialogModal').modal('hide')
      }, 10000);

</script>
```

here is the HTML button tag:

```
<button id="reqpay" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dialogModal" onclick="function();"> REQUEST PAYMENT
    </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `setTimeout` runs only once. You need to implement your code with `setInterval` and `clearInterval`.

setInterval MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

clearInterval MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval